# In need of a SaaS solution for semantic thesaurus matching

Tags: sas, semantics, thesaurus

I'm currently building a web application. In one of it's key processes the application need to match short phrases to other similar ones available in the DB.

The application needs to be able to match the phrase:

> Looking for a second hand car in good shape

To other phrases which basically have the same meaning but use different wording, such as:

> 2nd hand car in great condition needed

or

> searching for a used car in optimal quality

The phrases are length limited (say 250 chars), user generated & unstructured.

I'm in need of a service / company / some solution which can help / do these connections for me.

Can anyone give any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SAS text miner?  It *may* be suited to this kind of application.  I have only seen a demo of it and it would be able to tokenize the data just fine.  You may need some custom programming around the synonyms though.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.
I did think of another product from SAS - Sentiment Analysis, do you know it? Heard anything about it?
Thanks,
Roy

Comment: Nope haven't heard of it sorry.  Good luck.